# Eclipse equivalent for Visual Studio ALT + select text over multiple rows

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, selection, alt

In Visual Studio you can use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + your mouse to select a part of a line, over multiple lines. Here is an image to better explain what I mean:
[image]

And then you can copy it, or replace it all at the same time:
[image]

Is there an equivalent in Eclipse to do the same? At the moment I'm only looking to select and copy an entire list of around 100 codes in the middle of lines, and paste it somewhere else also in the middle, so I only need to be able to do the first image.

But if the second is also possible in Eclipse I'd love to hear it.

---

PS: I already know a work-around and have already succeeded in what I want, but would still love to know if this is possible in Eclipse. The workaround I've used:

1. Copied the entire text containing the codes I want to copy to Notepad++
2. Copy the entire text where I want to paste it also to Notepad++ in a new tab
3. Used <kbd>ALT</kbd> + Select to copy what I want (Note that you need to already hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> before selecting, unlike Visual Studio where you can be busy with selecting and hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> to change it.)
4. Use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + select again to paste it in the other file
5. Copy this modified file from Notepad++ back to Eclipse

^ It works, but isn't very efficient. Not that I use this feature a lot.

<sup><sup>([Source for images used](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnstudents/archive/2013/10/07/visual-studio-tips-selection-shortcuts-for-lazy-coders.aspx))</sup></sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse calls it *Block Select Mode*. This is what the icon looks like:

[image: block select mode icon]

You can toggle selection mode by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. You get a new (cross hairs) icon and then you can select blocks:

[image: block select in action]

Once you have your selection you should be able to type away.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it indeed works! "Eclipse, AFAIK does not natively support the second part of your question." This same feature does seem to work as well. I can select a part of private variables and type "public" to modify them all at the same time. I can also select a part and paste a copied part. So it indeed does all the same after toggling this Mode, so thanks.

Comment: Great, I am pleased, I have shared some of my knowledge and I am very pleased to have learned something new. I updated my post.